# how to git mv all files from public_html to public_html/public

Tags: git

I have a website in which I need to `git mv` all files from the `public_html` directory to `public_html/public`. How would I do this?

I tried creating the `public` directory with `mkdir public`, then `git mv` all files with `git mv ./. ./public/`, but of course this runs into problems because the destination is contained in the source. The error message returned by git is `fatal: bad source, source=, destination=public/`

I also tried creating a `public` directory outside of the git repository and `mv`'ing all files. This works, however the git history of files is lost because git treats this as deleting existing files and creating new ones rather than moving them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-k` to tell Git to skip any errors.

```
git mv -k public_html/* public_html/public/
```